# Performance analysis of HorizontalScrollView on PowerVR G6230

Tags: android, performance, scrollview, gpu

I tested the performance of HorizontalScrollView on a few devices and I noticed something I didn't expect. On a GPU that should perform pretty good, like 64-core PowerVR G6230, the scrolling is not as fluid as I'd expect in 1080p. What I see by inspecting with dumpsys is something like this while scrolling:

```
        0.64    2.54    0.82
        0.65    2.35    0.81
        0.71    2.12    10.37
        0.79    2.18    27.93
        0.42    1.12    0.71
        0.62    1.36    0.42
        0.54    1.32    0.41
        0.47    1.28    0.40
        0.42    1.13    0.68
        0.44    1.06    0.59
        0.40    1.11    0.70
        1.52    2.18    0.93
        0.70    2.12    0.81
        0.67    2.31    0.81
        0.66    2.35    0.81
        0.65    2.44    0.81
        1.00    2.00    0.99
        0.67    2.33    0.81
        0.81    2.02    0.89
        1.33    1.98    0.82
        0.65    2.34    0.81
        1.42    2.01    0.81
        1.79    2.15    0.83
        0.67    2.35    0.82
        0.66    2.37    0.82
        0.65    2.31    0.80
        0.64    2.34    0.81
        0.65    2.43    0.80
        0.98    2.00    6.06
        1.61    1.99    0.83
        0.66    2.37    0.82
        0.76    2.33    0.81
        0.64    2.35    0.82
        0.65    2.50    0.81
        0.63    2.33    0.81
        0.65    2.32    0.80
        1.31    1.98    0.81
        0.73    2.34    0.81
        1.26    2.04    0.81
        0.66    2.42    0.81
        0.63    2.33    0.80
        0.64    2.30    0.81
        0.62    2.37    0.80
        0.62    2.30    0.80
        0.64    2.30    0.80
        7.77    16.80   1.47
        0.52    6.15    0.47
        0.41    1.33    0.35
```

Which is exactly what I see: fluid scrolling with "interruptions", like frame drops. Anyone who has an explanation for those high values?

I've been able to improve a bit the frame rate by disabling hardware acceleration from the manifest and by enabling drawing cache on the ImageView's I place inside the scroll view, but still the result is not what I expected. Any idea why disabling the GPU results in better performance?

This is what I place in my Activity:

```
public static View getTestView(Context c) {
      LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(c);
      ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
      ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

      Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.colors_1);

      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
         ImageView iv = new ImageView(c);
         iv.setImageBitmap(b);
         //iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
         ll.addView(iv);
      }

      HorizontalScrollView sv = new HorizontalScrollView(c);
      sv.addView(ll);

      RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(c);
      rl.addView(sv, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params.leftMargin = 0;
      params.topMargin  = 0;
      rl.addView(new FpsImageView(c), params);

      return rl;
   }
```

Is there any possible optimization that I can apply to make the scrolling better? Maybe this is simply the best the GPU can do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're not getting random OutOfMemory exceptions, because basically what you're doing is inflating and allocating memory for 200 imageviews at the same time, which is a huge no-no.

If you want to see your app fly, what you really need is a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a horizontal [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html). That's not a 3 line change in the code, but the final result will be impressively fast, I guarantee. [Here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/12/23/android-recyclerview-simple-list/) you have a nice tutorial, but you can find a lot more in the web.